# Regular express for patterns like 1.1, 2.-1, 2.3.30

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking for a regular expression (to be used in javascript) that can match the following rules,

1. it consists of 0 or more parts
2. each part is a number. if it's positive, it's like 123. if negative, it's like -123
3. parts are connected/separated with a dot (.)

`/^(-?[0-9]*\.?)*$/g` is what i have, but it matches something like `1.1-1` which is considered illegal.

e.g. the ones considered legal
1, 1.1, 1.-3, 1.-3.-4.5

e.g. the ones considered illegal
1.1-1

Comment: `var test = str.split('.').every(part => /^-?\d+$/.test(part));`. `test` will be either `true` or `false`.

Comment: Is 1.-3.-4.5 legal or did you mean that to be a comma before -4.5?

Comment: 1.-3.-4.5 is considered legal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear if you're looking to match the sub-parts of the incorrect string "1.1-1" or not, but if you are, this should enable you to get what you're looking for.

Essentially, I've duplicated the first match subgroup and made subsequent subgroups optional with ?

```
(-?\d+)((\.(-?\d+))+)?
```

If you'd like to match the first part of any line that is malformed, here's one for that:

```
^-?\d+(\.(-?\d+))*
```

Here's a [Regexer sketch](http://regexr.com/3g51c).

Answer (score 0):

`/^-?\d+(\.-?\d+)*$/`:

```
^          : start
-?         : '-' (optional)
\d+        : digits (at least one)
(\.-?\d+)* : you can make it a non-capturing group if you want (?:\.-?\d+)*
    \.     : '.'
    -?     : '-' (optional)
    \d+    : digits (at least one)
    *      : match this group one or more times
$          : end
```

Look for **a valid number at the begining** (`^-?\d+`), then look for **a `.` followed by a valid number**, match as many as possible (`(\.-?\d+)*`).

---

**Example:**

```js
var tests = "1,-1,-1.-33,1.-4.-5.7,.1,1.,-1-1,1.5-7-8,1..1".split(','),
    regex = /^-?\d+(\.-?\d+)*$/;
    
tests.forEach(function(t) {
  console.log(t, " ===> ", regex.test(t));
});
```

---

[**Regex101 example**](https://regex101.com/r/3BYbil/2).